# How to create view to show gradient shadow from top to bottom, left to right for edittext android

Tags: android, background, android-edittext, gradient

I want to make background for my edittext in Android like this image below.Anyone knows about this, please provide me some example.Thanks

[image: image description here]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.